# How do I conditionally include a script file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there is a way to conditionally include a script file inside of `<script></script>` tags.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<script>
if(condition)
{
    <script src="/hts/functions.js"></script> //include this file if condition is met
}
</script>
```

I found this code:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

However, I don't understand how to use it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: There is if that `if` has something to do with Internet Explorer, then you could use conditional statements, otherwise, you could just "borrow" the async loading code that Google, facebook etc. uses for scripts, and place it in the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with $.getScript:

```
if(someConditionIsTrue){
    // load script from the server
    $.getScript( "somePath/onTheServer/script.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        // do something after the load is complete
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the script, add the code in the .getScript callback to your JavaScript for the page. Any code that depends on the script you are injecting should be included or called from inside the .getScript callback.

In the code you pasted, the `console.log` statements run after the injected script loads. Here's an example of using `$.getScript` to load the Underscore.js library and log the version of Underscore to the console:

```
var condition=true;
var pathToScript='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js';
if(condition){
    // load script from the server
    $.getScript( pathToScript, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        console.log(_.VERSION);
    });
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WA4f4/2/

I slightly modified your code so it would work in JSFiddle and to demonstrate that the code inside the callback to getScript can access variables from the injected script.